# Rails `create` Validation Requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Thank you in advance - while I think I have a working solution to this problem, I'm curious as to whether there's a better "Rails" way of tackling this and am also wondering whether there are any approaches I am missing.

I'm currently working on a project and would like to create a validation that will be considered upon every model's `create` method - I would like to specify that an id be included as an argument to each `create` method so that IDs are not created by `ActiveRecord` when all other properties are included.

ie `ExampleModel.create!(id: 'pre_specified_id', property: 'property_xyz')`

instead of

`ExampleModel.create!(property: 'property_xyz'`

While I know that I could simply add a validation on every model, given that I'd like for this to be performed on every model, it seems better to instead add a validation on `ApplicationRecord` so that every model will possess this method. As an example:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    validate :id_presence

    private

    def id_presence
        raise ArgumentError, 'An ID must be defined' if id.nil?
    end
end
```

Is utilizing a validation on `ApplicationRecord` the appropriate way to manage this validation or is there a better way to go about adding this requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the id attribute is not even shown by Rails in the scema.rb file on the basis that it shouldn't need to be changed. It would be good to understand why a custom id is required. Could a second pre_specified_id for your specific purpose be included in the schema in addition to the built in Rails id?

Comment: @JohnHanlon I second that idea, it almost always best to go with the Rails flow as much as you can. Just declare some other column as your de facto unique identity, you can name it whatever you want.